# How does one read checkboxes created in an Angular 6 template

Tags: angular, checkbox, checked

I have some checkboxes being created this way:

```
  <table>
  <tr class='collectionList' *ngFor="let option of configurationTemplate">
    <td class='formLabel'>{{option.name}}</td>
    <td>
    <ng-container *ngIf="option.type == 'boolean'">
      <input class='configurationForm' id='id-{{option.name}}' type='checkbox' name="{{option.name}}"  [checked]="option.value"  [(ngModel)]="option.value"   />
    </ng-container>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

I when I click a button, I fire a method in my controller that does this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('configurationForm');
    var obj = {};
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
      var element = elements[i];
      var name = element.id.replace("id-", "");
      if(element.className.indexOf('dirty')>-1) {
        //console.log(element.id);
        obj[name] = 1;
      } else {
        //console.log(element.id);
        obj[name] = 0;
      }

    }
```

The problem is that there is no property in the elements I am looping through to tell me whether or not they are checked. So I ended up looking at the className (as you see) -- but this doesn't work when the checkboxes haven't been changed. I just want a checked property to determine whether or not the checkbox is checked, but Angular doesn't seem to provide one.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  This stuff is super easy with plain (no-framework) Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the element to HtmlInputElement, refer code below:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('configurationForm');
var obj = {};
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
  var element = <HTMLInputElement>elements[i];
  var name = element.id.replace("id-", "");
  if(element.className.indexOf('dirty')>-1) {
    console.log(element.checked);
    //console.log(element.id);
    obj[name] = 1;
  } else {
    //console.log(element.id);
    obj[name] = 0;
  }

}
```